# ibatisを用いたSQL

Tags: sql

ibatisで受け取ったList型のキーワードで
キーワードの数だけSELECTを行いたいと考えています。
キーワードと一致した分だけポイントを加算していく方法は無いでしょうか？
イメージとしては下記のSQLのように加算していきたいと考えています。
解決方法が有ればどなたかお願い致します。

```
SELECT tbl1.id,point1 + point2 AS point
FROM 
(SELECT user.id, user_point1.point1
FROM tbl_user AS user
    (SELECT id,100::integer AS point1
    FROM tbl_user
    WHERE user_name LIKE '%田中%') AS user_point1
    ON user.id = user_point1.id
) AS tbl1
FULL OUTER JOIN
        (SELECT id,100::integer AS point2
        FROM tbl_user
        WHERE user_name ILIKE '%田中%') AS user_point2
        ON tbl1.id = user_point2.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

質問にあるSQLを出力するためには、キーワードの他にテーブルのエイリアスとしてインデックスの値が必要となります。
`MyBatis`であれば`<foreach>`要素で`index`が参照できますが、`iBatis`の`<iterate>`では難しいのではないかと思います。

同様の結果が取得できるエイリアスが不要なSQLとしては

```
SELECT id
     , (CASE WHEN user_name LIKE '%田中%' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END)
     + (CASE WHEN user_name LIKE '%hoge%' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END)
     + (CASE WHEN user_name LIKE '%fuga%' THEN 100 ELSE 0 END) AS point
  FROM tbl_user
```

や

```
SELECT id, SUM(point) AS point
  FROM
(
    SELECT id, 100 AS point FROM tbl_user
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 100 AS point FROM tbl_user
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, 100 AS point FROM tbl_user
)
```

が思いつきます。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！
この様な方法があったんですね